# Find out which processes use the most memory and kill them

Tags: bash, unix, memory-management

I currently have a bash script that checks my machine memory state and sends me an email alert whenever its memory exceeds some threshold, my question here is:

- Is there a way to find out which processes are consuming the most memory on the machine and kill them within the script ?

Here is my script, as it is for now:

```
#!/bin/bash

############################################################
#                  Memory usage function                   #
#           Captures memory usage in percentage            #
#  Sends an email alert if memory usage exceeds threshold  #
############################################################

memory_check() {
    total_ram=`cat /proc/meminfo | grep 'MemTotal' | awk '{print $2}'`;
    free_ram=`cat /proc/meminfo | grep 'MemFree' | awk '{print $2}'`;
    used_ram=$(($total_ram - $free_ram))
    mem_percent=$(($used_ram * 100 / $total_ram))
    machine_name=`hostname`
    threshold=95
    if [ $mem_percent -gt $threshold ]; then
        echo "Memory usage has exceeded $threshold% threshold and was at $mem_percent%." > memory_alert_report
        mailx -s "Memory resource alarm on $machine_name !" my@adress.com < memory_alert_report
    else
        exit;
    fi
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Yes there is a way. But why would you want to start indiscriminately killing processes? And what have you actually _tried_ so far? This looks like homework...

Comment: @arco444 The thing is, I need to kill processes when memory exceeds 95% usage because it shouldn't reach that point, and if it does it means my program has gone crazy and I need to kill it before it reaches 100%, like it did not so long ago, and it will break my production environment... So far I've made some research without finding any answer.

Comment: I know that my program will be the one using the most memory, and if this occurs during night I would like it to be killed asap.

Comment: A better idea would be for your *program* to monitor its memory usage, and exit itself if it is using too much.

Comment: Just set a ulimit on your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @chepner suggested, I'm now monitoring memory through my program thanks to a Java socket which will receive a signal if memory in to high and then will nicely shutdown the process.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use top in batch mode ? e.g

```
$ top -b -n 1
```

will dump out process info (including memory info) to standard out. You can then redirect into `sort` (sorting on the appropriate column) and extract the pids for the top memory consumers.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't address your question, but I hope it helps simplify your shell scripts.

When capturing MemTotal from /proc/meminfo, your original line is:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep 'MemTotal' | awk '{print $2}'
```

You don't need to use `cat` to feed a file into `grep`.  Just do this:

```
grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}'
```

Even better, awk is implicitly greplike, so you can replace your entire pipeline with this:

```
awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo
```

That means "If my line matches `/MemTotal/`, execute `print $2`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the original question, even though OP found a better solution to his problem, 'cause I wanted a script like this for other reasons:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
# kills the process using the most memory

# -A: list all processes
# sort in reverse order of resident set size
pid=`ps -A --sort -rss --format pid --no-headers | head -n1`

kill $pid
sleep 15 # give it a chance to exit gracefully
kill -9 $pid # otherwise, kill forcefully
```

Thanks to Alex D for [his answer on Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268428/73905) that gave me the basic ps syntax and Jon Jensen for [his article](http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/08/automatically-kill-process-using-too.html) that gave me the idea to kill forcefully after waiting.